# How many end ships can you find in an end city?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My friend and I want to go to the end and get 2 elytras. How many can we find in a single city?

Comment: Maximum one ship per city. Could be zero. Never two. Find multiple cities.

Answer (score 4):

Every End city either has one ship or none.

Answer (score 1):

Every End City has either one ship or none. Each ship has exactly 1 elytra.

You can occasionally find two end cities generated within each other (similar to the massive villages that are sometimes generated), in which case there is a chance that you may find two ships at once, but this is incredibly rare.